# How to delete only the large movie files from iPhoto (and not all movies)?

Tags: icloud, memory, storage, macos

I have an iPhone, (work) MacBook and (home) Windows PC, and have set automated download from iPhotos to my home PC. Like many of us, I've filled up my iPhoto library with large videos.

I can see from the file sizes I can view on the PC downloads, that half of my iCloud storage is taken up by just 100 video files of size >100 MB. I can easily back these up on the PC, but then to free up storage I'd like to delete them from iPhotos. I don't really want to remove all movies from iPhotos - that would be overkill - just the large ones.

While I can see the filenames and sizes on the PC, iPhotos hides that data. Is there any way to select the movie files > 100 MB in iPhotos and delete them?